# SQL server agent does not run SSIS package with python script

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, visual-studio, ssis

I have a Python script which I have implemented in a SSIS package with "Execute process task". When I run the package in Visual Studio, everything works fine. However, when I run the package with SQL server agent it fails. How could this been solved?

Error code:
Executed as user: DESKTOP-3SDAFD\4664656. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 15.0.2000.5 for 32-bit  Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft. All rights reserved. Code: 0xC0029151     Source: Transform_PD Execute Process Task     Description: In Executing "C:\Python\Python392\python.exe" "myscript.py" at "C:\script", The process exit code was "1" while the expected was "0".  End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  16:50:28  Finished: 16:50:41  Elapsed:  12.718 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.

I run the following code in the .py file within SSIS package:

```
import sys
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"download.default_directory" : "C:\\DownloadFolder\\"}
option.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
option.add_argument("--start-maximized");
chromedriver = "C:\Script\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver, options=option)


BASE_URl = "https://www.mywebsite.com"
driver.get(BASE_URl)
time.sleep(3)

link2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("mypath").text; 

link = driver.find_element_by_link_text(link2)
link.click()

time.sleep(10)

driver.quit()
sys.exit(0)
```

Python confiquration in SSIS:
[image]
I noticed that if I change the Python script in the SSIS to another simple script, SQL agent can finish the job. Can somebody help me with this error?

I use SSMS.

Comment: Can you show the code you are running? And did you install the chrome driver onto the agent itself?

Comment: What do you mean by "installing the chrome diver into the agent itself?"
I have put the Chromedriver in the folder where the script.py is located. When I run the script from IDLE it works.

Comment: depends on how you are calling that script. When you are running the script in IDLE, is the working directory the same as `script.py`? On the SQL agent, is this the same, or are you calling the script from elsewhere? You might need to pass the actual location of the driver to selenium

Comment: Please post the code you are running in the question, as well

Comment: Yes the working directory is the same as the script, I added to code to the post. Is this sufficient for you? Thank you!

Comment: when you run the python script from CMD does it works? @Zayfaya83 ?

Comment: Yes, the sript is working fine in CMD and if I execute the package from Visual Studio it is also working.